# Windows 7 - wireless connection sharing

Tags: windows, windows-7, wifi, connection-sharing

I am trying to share my mobile broadband Internet connection with other machines via Wi-Fi and am running Windows 7. Users are able to connect to my machine, but they are not able to obtain an Internet connection once they connect to me. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Does the Windows firewall block this?

Comment: Can they ping an external ip address, like 72.14.221.99 (belongs to Google)?

Comment: Nope, they are never assigned an ip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable Internet connection sharing.

> Go to **Control Panel**, select **Network and Sharing Center**.
>
> Click on the link **"Set up a Connection or Network"**.
>
> Select the option **“Set up a wireless ad hoc (computer-to-computer) network”**.
>   [image: connection]
>
> Type in the **Network name** and select the **Security Type** (WPA 2).
>
> Click on **"Turn on Internet connection sharing"**.

Windows Help and How-to : [Set up a computer-to-computer (ad hoc) network](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-SG/help/293c504f-b944-4d5d-835c-f080129bd5dc1033.mspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com) allows you to easily share an Internet connection with other devices via Wi-Fi by turning any Windows 7 computer into a wireless router. Wi-Fi enabled devices connect to Virtual Router just like any other Wi-Fi network.