# How can I enable WPA2 on Windows 7 when sharing an ethernet connection over wireless?

Tags: networking, security, windows-7, wifi, wpa

I have shared my ethernet connection over wireless in Windows 7 using the method outlined in the accepted answer here: [Windows 7 - wireless connection sharing](https://serverfault.com/questions/29117/windows-7-wireless-connection-sharing).

My wireless card is a [TP-Link TL-WN821N](http://www.tp-link.com/products/productDetails.asp?class=&content=spe&pmodel=TL-WN821N), which, according to the specs, supports WPA2.

When I am in the *Setup an Ad Hoc Network* configuration screen, I only have the option of *WEP* under *Security Type*:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

How can I enable WPA2 as an option? I am using the latest driver, v3.5.0.12 dated 11/26/2009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 supports a Soft AP mode that can be used to create a more secure sharing environment as it supports WPA2\AES. This works with most WLAN Nics but there may be issues with some older kit.

The steps you need to follow are:

1: Open up an administrator command prompt.

2: Create the SoftAP config:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow SSID=PeerWithWPA2 key=WPA2Password keyusage=persistent
```

3: You will now need to modify your ICS settings to allow sharing from your main internet adapter to this new network. You manage this from the properties->sharing tab of the network adapter that is your primary internet connection. This can be the same WLAN adapter that will be used for the Soft AP.

4: Start the SoftAP

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

5: Connect to this from your other systems just as you would connect to any AP that provides a WPA2 secured SSID

There is a full guide with screenshots available [here](http://tameyourpc.blogspot.com/2009/07/windows-7-as-wireless-access-point.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc cannot use WPA2, only WEP. The support for your card with WPA2, is for when it is connecting to an Infrastructure type wireless network.